# Failed to verify client certificate when using autocert

Tags: go, ssl

Full error is

```
tls: failed to verify client certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

code used for getting tls.Config is

```
manager := &autocert.Manager{
    Prompt:     autocert.AcceptTOS,
    Cache:      autocert.DirCache(certificatesCachePath),
    HostPolicy: autocert.HostWhitelist(hosts...),
    Email:      email,
}

t = &tls.Config{
    ClientAuth:     tls.VerifyClientCertIfGiven,
    Renegotiation:  tls.RenegotiateOnceAsClient,
    MaxVersion:     tls.VersionTLS12,
    GetCertificate: manager.GetCertificate,
    NextProtos:     defaultNextProtocols
}
```

I really cant understand where is a problem and how to fix it

Comment: This is about the **client certificate received** by the server, not about the **server certificate** used by the server. autocert cares about the server certificate and thus is unrelated to this. The client certificate is issued by a CA not trusted by the server. The configuration for ClientCAs in tls.Config is relevant to setup which CA are trusted for client authentication.

Comment: Is there anything i may do with tis err? Client is in another city and didn't used any specific ca's, i think client don't know what is it at all, default safari in mac with big sur.

Comment: Why do you ask for client certificates in the first place and expect these to be valid? You treat client certificates as optional so you don't care if none is send. But if the client sends a certificate you expect it to be valid. I recommend that you either don't ask for a certificate in the first place (`ClientAuth: tls.NoClientCert`) or treat as optional and not verify it (`ClientAuth: tls.RequestClientCert`).